# Casting numbers to specifically sized integers in JavaScript (replicate Solidity functionality)

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to replicate the following Solidity view function in JS/web3.js

```
function addPhase(
    uint16 _phase,
    uint64 _originalId
  )
    public
    view
    returns (uint80)
  {
    return uint80(uint256(_phase) << 64 | _originalId);
  }
```

I know that the **<<** and **|** bit operators directly translate to JavaScript, but I can't seem to get a correct result with the casting to integers part, seems JavaScript doesn't support this easily.

Eg, passing in parameters (**1,5132**) in the solidity function gives a result of **18446744073709556748**

How can I replicate this formula in Javascript?
Here's my starting point (which doesn't give a correct response)

```
console.log(1 << 64 | 5132)
```

Comment: There are two kinds of numbers in JavaScript: double-precision (64-bit) floating point numbers, and (in recent environments) "big int" values, which are integers with unlimited precision.

Comment: Try `console.log(1n << 64n | BigInt(5132))`, for example. Notice `n` on literals, and `BigInt` function for conversion of an existing numeric value.

Comment: @Amadan that works thanks. I just have the n on the end of the answer now too (18446744073709556748n). I guess I can just strip it or something?

Comment: No, just `10n.toString()` will give you the correct string representation. Or even just implicitly `"" + 10n`, or interpolating `${10n}` inside a template string...